# Is rsyslog compatible with syslog-ng?

Tags: rhel, rsyslog, syslog, syslog-ng, rsyslogd

I am doing a project where the organisation uses syslog-ng for the central remote logging servers and this will surely not change.

The application suite that I am developing on, is using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8, which will surely also not change.

From my understanding, RHEL 8 ships standard with rsyslog and if I want to use syslog-ng, it is necessary to install it from either the EPEL repositories or the "suplementary" repository.

However, I am working on private internal network without internet access and the internal RHEL update server does not provide these repositories.

So my main question is how do I get my application logs on RHEL 8 to the remote syslog-ng server?

I suppose my options are as follows:

1. try to somehow get syslog-ng installed internally on my client (cumbersome option)
2. perhaps rsyslog is already compatible with syslog-ng, so I can simply log there? (wishful option)
3. convert rsyslog logs to syslog-ng before pushing it to the the log server (undesirable option)
   Could you guys please provide some advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The format for syslog messages is very precisely defined. RFC 5424 from 2009 set the standard for all messages. Any conforming client/server will be able to talk with any other. You can count on `rsyslog` being able to talk to `syslog-ng`.

Comment: As @doneal24 wrote, unless you configure rsyslog to send the logs in some nonstandard format, syslog-ng will understand them for sure, having rsyslog clients feed a syslog-ng server is a common usecase.